# Global SQL connection in background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to create a small Windows Forms App with .Net 4.0

Part of my program needs to connect to to a database but when I do the following:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

try
{
    conn.Open();
} 

....
```

The whole program kind of just hangs until the connection is made. What I want to do, is be able to make/open this connection, I suppose, in the background. So the program will still respond to button clicks etc.

Also, how do I make this single connection available globally to my program?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inform the user that you're connecting to the database, perhaps with one of those infinite progress bars, and use the wait cursor.

Answer (score 5):

You should address the problem of why it takes so long to get a connection. It sounds more like you want to treat the **symptoms** which is that it hangs your application.

> How do I make this single connection available globally to my program?

This is bad practice. Connections to databases should be kept open for the **shortest** duration possible. Acquire a connection just before you need to use it, then close it as soon as you're finished. Since you're using C# you can take advantage of the `using` block which manages disposable resources for you:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    try {
        conn.Open();
        // do things here...
    }
    catch (Exception) {
    }
}
```

Even if you wanted to do something like open the connection asynchronously what purpose would it serve? Your users would have a more responsive UI but still be unable to do anything in the application until the connection was established.

Answer (score -1):

The case which you want to do is not suggestted because you should make the operations with db as possible as quick.